# Deleting from a subsonic collection bound to a winforms datagridview

Tags: data-binding, collections, datagridview, subsonic

I have a winforms application that I added a DataGridView bound to a subsonic collection via a BindingSource to it.

The grid works *fine* for adding/editing (except for the [display of the ComboBox column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865141/populating-a-datagridview-combobox-column-with-subsonic-vb-net)) but I can't get it to delete rows correctly from the database.

If I delete a row from the DataGridView, I can't problematically determine that the collection is dirty  and when I call the. BatchSave method of the subsonic collection it deletes all the rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the 2.2 version SaveAll should also delete the items you removed from your datagridview.

In 2.1 you have to make a call to

```
ItemCollection.ProcessDeletedItems()
```

too

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
private void productBindingSource_ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ((ProductCollection)productBindingSource.List).SaveAll();
}
```